# Java download mobile version of webpage source

Tags: java, url, mobile, web

I need to download webpage source code of some website. Specifically I need to download the source as the mobile version. For example, for Facebook, the program should download the source code of m.facebook.com. Note that the `URL` passed into the program is the normal `URL` (`facebook.com`, `cnn.com`, etc.) I know how to download a normal webpage using `URL` class but I did not see any mobile version switch in `URL` class. Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no switch. When you request the page you will need to adjust the headers that are sent with the http request. Such as the user agent-header. Make sure you follow any redirects that are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for a plugin for your favorite web browser that lets you change the user agent string.

The user agent string is how the browser tells the web site what kind of device and browser is trying to access the page and the web site can then render a page that's appropriate for your device and browser (for the web sites that have customized versions of their pages).

Answer (score 0):

Request the URL with a mobile useragent (android, ios) and call e.g.: getInputStream() on the connection object to follow the redirect. Then you can get the source code.

If you are unsure how to do that, look up how to send HTTP header information with java.

Here is a list of mobile user agent strings: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent